# SQL - How to get newest data of same date created

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, mariadb

I have table images with uploaded date field. How can I get the newest image if 2 or more images were uploaded in same day.

**1.We check on hours, minutes or seconds.**

**2.If the H:M:S are same, check on the sequences of inserted ID.**

```
ID |     URL    |           create           |
1  |   01.jpg   |     2017-02-23 10:24:41    |<<same H:M:s
2  |   02.jpg   |     2017-02-23 10:24:41    |<<same H:M:s
3  |   03.jpg   |     2017-02-23 10:50:00    |<<same H
4  |   04.jpg   |     2017-02-24 21:50:00    |<<others
5  |   05.jpg   |     2017-03-28 17:50:00    |<<others
```

Output: I want to get only

```
3  |   03.jpg   |     2017-02-23 10:50:00    |<< newer than 1, 2
4  |   04.jpg   |     2017-02-24 21:50:00    |
5  |   05.jpg   |     2017-03-28 17:50:00    |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all the rows with the max timestamp on a given day, use

```
select created,max(id) maxid
from (select t1.*,(select count(distinct created) from t 
                   where created >=t1.created 
                   and cast(created as date)=cast(t1.created as date)) rn
       from t t1) x
     where rn=1
```

If there can be ties on the latest timestamp and only the latest id is needed in that case, the above query can be extended to the following.

```
select y.maxid id,t.url,t.created 
from (
     select created,max(id) maxid
     from (select t1.*,(select count(distinct created) from t 
                        where created >=t1.created 
                        and cast(created as date)=cast(t1.created as date)) rn
           from t t1) x
     where rn=1
     group by created
) y 
join t on t.id=y.maxid and t.created=y.created
```

Comment: Oh...I didn't see this before. But where can I put the table_name into the query?

Comment: replace t wherever you see it with your tablename

Comment: Oh, I have successfully run you query....but It was quite difficult to apply to my project. I use CakePHP to build the query. With this one I am scare that difficult for me. Anyway thank for your helps. (Y)

Comment: The `ID` column appears to be a primary key auto increment column.  If so, then I think it should be safe to assume that it follows the timestamp in order.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT MAX(create) AS latest, MAX(ID) AS maxID
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY DATE(create)
) t2
    ON t1.create = t2.latest AND
       t1.ID     = t2.maxID
```

Comment: perhaps add a condition to handle multiple rows with the max create. in that case the op only needs the max id.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but the result is same. The records still select all. Here my query `SELECT UP.*
FROM user_pictures UP
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT MAX(created) AS latest
    FROM user_pictures
    GROUP BY DATE(created)
) UP2
    ON UP.created = UP2.latest`

Comment: @vkp I have added this logic

Comment: That was great. I have successfull get data what I want with your updating. Thank for you help.

Comment: @TommyDo .. you should be aware that this query will not give you the expected result if the latest timestamp on a given day doesn't have the maximum id.

Comment: @vkp: you are right. If the ID is not maximum the query is fail. Do you have any better one?

Answer (score 0):

How about using an `ORDER BY` and a `LIMIT`?

```
SELECT *
FROM Images
ORDER BY create DESC, ID DESC
LIMIT 1
```

The ORDER by sorts the images by create, then ID. The limit selects only 1. This should select only the newest photo.

Comment: ORDER BY just order the data with fields what you want. It will select all data. I think @Tim Biegeleisen's answer was correct.

Comment: I actually just figured out that you want 1 record PER DAY.